# How to get creation time and last write time of a file

Tags: c, time, system

I'm opening several files , and want to add to my struct the creation time of the file and the  last write time. Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Depending on OS & filesystem, the creation time might not be stored at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

The `struct stat` contains several fields describing time and date information, in particular

```
time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) to read the last write time (see `stat.st_mtime`).

I'm not aware of a portable way to read creation time.  On Windows you could use [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)